# Windows 10 mass storage data loss due to sudden shutdown?

Tags: windows-10, data-recovery

I am a bit confused about this one. I was working on stuff and then my battery ran out of juice (I'll leave out why). So my Windows 10 laptop quickly powers down.
Once I recharged it it reopened up everything I was working on. So it seems like it quickly dumped my memory to storage and restored that (including unsaved work).

The weird and kinda scary part is that data from my drive was missing. I am not sure if there is other stuff missing but two folders from my Desktop are gone. One with Images which I had opened up with the Windows Photos app when my system shutdown.

I can't explain myself how this is even possible? Any Ideas? Or Suggestions on how I could recover those files?

Comment: If you know the name of the folder, search for it in explorer.

Comment: It's probably not gone. It's likely the addresses to the files are gone. Do not write anything to the drive before you run standard data recovery processes.